# Javascript loop inside json object

Tags: javascript, arrays

Want the check for every element in the elements object  if it has  x and y value in positions , and if not apply some default values for x and y.

```
Debug_Elements_List:{
"elements":{["001","name"],["002","name"]},
"element_position":{"positions": [{"element_name":"001","x":"60","y":"24"},{"element_name":"002","x":"174","y":"21"}]}
}
```

Comment: You provided a goal and some sample data but haven't shown any code attempts to solve the issue yourself or explained the problems you are having achieving your goal. Stack Overflow isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for others to help fix your code when it doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Correct your JSON and use forEach loop

```js
var d = [{
  Debug_Elements_List: {
    "elements": [
      ["001", "name"],
      ["002", "name"]
    ],
    "element_position": {
      "positions": [{
        "element_name": "001",
        "x": "60",
        "y": "24"
      }, {
        "element_name": "002",
        "x": "174",
        
      }]
    }
  }
}]
d.forEach(e => {
  e.Debug_Elements_List.element_position.positions.forEach(k => {
    if (!k.hasOwnProperty('x')) 
        k.x = 0;
        if (!k.hasOwnProperty('y')) 
        k.y = 0;

        })
})
console.log(d)
```

Comment: for (let row of this.data) {
               element_ id = row[1];
               element_name = row[2];
              this.DrawElements(element_name, element_id);
               x= x+100;}     ,i had a function like this for drawing the elements inside  and incrementing the x all the time but i couldnt loop inside and check if there were any positions